# Django 1.9 : ManyToManyField in custom User Profile causes AttributeError: 'ManyToManyRel' object has no attribute 'field_name'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a custom user profile in Django. Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

class AppCodeUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, appcode, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, appcode and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            appcodes=appcode
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, appcode, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, appcode and password.
        """
        print("Creating superuser...")
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            appcodes=appcode
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class AppCode(models.Model):
    appcode = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

    def get_appcode(self):
        return self.appcode

class AppCodeUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    appcodes = models.ManyToManyField(AppCode)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AppCodeUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['appcodes']

    def get_appcodes(self):
        return "\n".join([p.appcode for p in self.appcodes.all()])

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

so `AppCodeUser` is my class for each user. Each user will have an email, password and a **list** of appcodes. I have created a class `AppCode` for this.

Here is my admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from models import AppCodeUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = AppCodeUser
        fields = ('email', 'appcodes')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = AppCodeUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'appcodes', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin', 'get_appcodes')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Appcode info', {'fields': ('get_appcodes',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'get_appcodes', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(AppCodeUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

i have put `get_appcodes` wherever necessary

when i try to  create a super user, this happens

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
Email address: asd@we.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 52, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\qwe\asd\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 127, in handle
    ) if field.remote_field else '',
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyRel' object has no attribute 'field_name'
```

i have no idea what this error means. Is there something wrong in my config?

Comment: This issue is also present in Django 1.11, might be worth updating the title.